# Get-WindowsSearchSetting isnt in Windows 7

Tags: powershell, citrix

Get-windowssearchsetting doesnt seem to be in Windows 7 PS

We have a Citrix environment, Windows Search is disabled as part of best practice. Currently on the image I will enable the Windows Search service and change what is indexed. Since Get-windowssearchsetting or set-windowssearchsetting is not avaliable in Windows 7 what are my options?

This isnt a duplicate of [How to add a location to windows 7/8 search index using batch or vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390514/how-to-add-a-location-to-windows-7-8-search-index-using-batch-or-vbscript)
Because everything in that article no longer seems to apply to Windows 7 but in Server 2012 only.

Comment: Its close but the DLL does not seem to be available from MS.

Comment: And if I google Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll it takes me to framework 4.0

Comment: @benH Did you even read the article that your stating this question is a duplicate of?